# Is it possible to add an image at the side of a form component?

Tags: google-forms

I'm trying to add an images to the left of each of my form components (multiple choice, linear scale, etc). Basically I want an image to serve as an icon for each form component.

[image]

Adding an image like this:

[image]

Is just ridiculous because it puts the image *above* the form component.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this time there does not seem to be an option to choose the position of the picture.
Above is the only choice to make at the moment.